# How to test whether FILE exists and is readable in D

Tags: file, testing, permissions, d, exists

How do you determine if a file is readable in D?  I've searched both google and D's docs and stuff multiple times--I've also searched SO multiple times--but I haven't been able to find **anything** on testing whether a given file is readable.  I know how to do it, theoretically, in C using __freadable--I even tried to make an external call to __freadable in D but I got the following linking error:

```
ldc2  -O2 -dw -g -wi -I/usr/include/stdio_ext.h -c ket.d ket.o
ldc2  -O2 -dw -g -wi -I/usr/include/stdio_ext.h -ofket ket.o 
ket.o: In function `_Dmain':
/home/hav3lock/sy.l/repos/pub_rel/ket/ket.d:47: undefined reference to `_D3ket4mainFAAyaZv11__freadableUPOS4core4stdc5stdio6_iobufZi'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: /usr/bin/gcc failed with status: 1
make: *** [ket] Error 1
```

I read some more on calling C stuff in D and apparently I'd need to rewrite the stdio_ext.h C header--where __freadable lives--as a D header or something like that, and that amount of work is beyond the scope of what I'm trying to do.

I just want to be able to figure out if a given file is readable so that I can determine whether the file exists and if it is also readable all in one go.  If I was writing this sucker in bash I'd just use

```
[[ -r FILE ]]
```

to test whether FILE exists and read permission to it is granted, but I just can't find out how to do the equivalent in D... any ideas?

---

Tried using getAttributes, but D complains about:

```
no property 'getAttributes' for type 'File'
```

Here's how I'm using *getAttributes*

```
    auto file_a = File(proc_auto[hdex], "r");
    writeln(file_a.getAttributes);
```

Comment: I also figured out how to utilize __freadable

`extern (C) int __freadable(FILE *__fp);

int Dfreadable(string string0)
{
    auto file_a = File( string0, "r");

    return __freadable(file_a.getFP);
}`  Then you just pass the name of the file that you want to check to 'Dfreadable()' and it'll tell you whether the given file is reabable or not.  See 'man 3 __freadable' for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why googling when you have the excellent Phobos reference on http://www.dlang.org ?

What you seek is the [std.file.getAttributes()](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#.getAttributes) function.

Comment: oh, forgot to mention that bit--I get an error when I try to use getAttributes, but maybe its because I'm trying to use it on a file handle instead of running it as 'std.file.getAttributes(FILE)'.  Let me add it real quick like.

Comment: Yeah, it was a case of incorrect usage on my part, thanks for the help.  :)

Comment: Glad I helped. :) To quote Andrei - "Phobos rox!"